# Sudo apt - get Crashed

Tags: apt, system-installation, updates, sudo, gitlab

I am unable to update

```
samkit@samkit-Latitude-E7450:~$ sudo apt update
E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source https://gitlab.com/paulcarroty/vscodium-deb-rpm-repo/raw/repos/debs/ vscodium: /usr/share/keyrings/vscodum-archive-keyring.gpg != 
E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source https://gitlab.com/paulcarroty/vscodium-deb-rpm-repo/raw/repos/debs/ vscodium: /usr/share/keyrings/vscodum-archive-keyring.gpg != 
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

ALso i am Unable to Install anything
For E.g

```
samkit@samkit-Latitude-E7450:~$ sudo apt install git
E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source https://gitlab.com/paulcarroty/vscodium-deb-rpm-repo/raw/repos/debs/ vscodium: /usr/share/keyrings/vscodum-archive-keyring.gpg != 
E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source https://gitlab.com/paulcarroty/vscodium-deb-rpm-repo/raw/repos/debs/ vscodium: /usr/share/keyrings/vscodum-archive-keyring.gpg != 
E: The list of sources could not be read.
E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source https://gitlab.com/paulcarroty/vscodium-deb-rpm-repo/raw/repos/debs/ vscodium: /usr/share/keyrings/vscodum-archive-keyring.gpg != 
E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source https://gitlab.com/paulcarroty/vscodium-deb-rpm-repo/raw/repos/debs/ vscodium: /usr/share/keyrings/vscodum-archive-keyring.gpg != 
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Answer (score 1):

Disable that source for the moment and try again.

Check `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` and `/etc/apt/sources.list`. Comment that source out with a hash sign `#` and run `sudo apt update` again.

This https://gitlab.com/paulcarroty/vscodium-deb-rpm-repo/raw/repos/debs/ does not exist (404 error). https://gitlab.com/paulcarroty/vscodium-deb-rpm-repo does, and it contains instructions how to set up that apt source.